# Installing CentOS 6.3 wrong hard drives order?

Tags: centos, partition, installation

I am trying to install CentOS 6.3 on new server that has 2xSSD and 1xHDD drives connected to mainboard's SATA ports by following order:

```
SSD1 -> SATA1
SSD2 -> SATA2
HDD1 -> SATA3
```

On the installation process CentOS shows me hard drives by this order:

```
/sda -> that is actually SSD2
/sdb -> HDD1
/sdc -> SSD1
```

It looks like CentOS assigns it randomly rather by the SATA connection order.

My question is: What the order of drives `/sd*` depending on? And how can I change it to be by the order it connected to SATA? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unexpected ordering is why mounting devices via UUID was invented.  For example, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID

Comment: I just removed all drives and add them one by one after installation, strange but it was only the way to install them in proper order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason they're out of order is that your system BIOS is configured to present them out of order. Unfortunately, this is all too common. Fortunately, it really doesn't matter much, since you will only rarely refer to the drives by their actual device names. As long as the (grub) bootloader got installed to the right place, you will be fine.

Comment: Yes, confirming that hard drives were not correctly ordered in BIOS, after I fixed it there is nothing has been changed while installing because drives somehow had remember their order places. I just removed them and connected one by one after then installation, that is helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed all drives and add them one by one after installation, strange but it was only the way to install them in proper order I have not found any fast way to fix it...